# Incorrect interprocess reading

Tags: linux, process, server, client, communication

I'm doing a client/server communication system with shared memory. I'm writing with the client the PID which the Server will then read. The problem is that when I try to read the value, it only reads the least signficant 8 bits. Here's a chunk of the code:

```
 int receive(void* data, void * connection) {
   connection_t * c = (connection_t *)connection;

   printf("PRINTING: %d \n", *(c->address));


   return 0;
}

void notify_server() {
  int mem_id = shmget(PUBLIC_KEY, PAGE_SIZE, PERMISSION_FLAGS);
  int * address = shmat(mem_id, NULL, 0);
  int sem_id = semget(PUBLIC_KEY, 1, PERMISSION_FLAGS);

  *address = (pid_t)PRIVATE_KEY;
  printf("FROM CLIENT, PRINT MY PID --- %d\n", *address);
}
```

The structure is:

```
typedef struct {
  int id;
  char * address;
  struct shmid_ds data;
  int sem_id;
  struct sembuf sb;
} connection_t;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `address` field is a `char`: `char * address;`

So of course `*(c->address)` will give a `char` which is 8 bits.

Comment: The solution is to cast the address to (int *) before dereferencing the pointer .

Comment: Why not declare it as an `int` in the struct?

Comment: Because in general the data in the shared memory will be treated as a string, this is an exception to the rule.